# How to replace custom bbcode tag containing structured content?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, bbcode

I have a string as this one: `"[dr]azAZ09-09[/dr]"`

Example: `[dr]my name here-25[/dr]`

I want to get all the elements:

```
my name here
-
25
```

How can I write the `preg_split()` expression (or another function)?

Comment: Does your string *always* start with `[dr]` and end with `[/dr]`?

Comment: What defines "element"? For instance, what do you expect for `[dx]a?})---7y3/!4[$[/dx]abcdef`?

Comment: Can you include more sample data?

Comment: @Lilia There are more than 10 different "correct" ways to do this.  We simply don't know enough about your question requirements. Please explain how your input data may vary.  Tell us more about the process logic so that we can be sure to offer you the best possible pattern.  Is `[dr]azAZ09-09[/dr]` an example of an entire input string or might it be a substring of a much larger portion of text?

Comment: I explain better: I extract several posts from the DB.


If in the posts insertion textarea the user enters the following "bbcode":
`[dr] every thing - number [/dr]`
I must intercept this string and turn it into a quote, during the insert in the DB.


Of course, the user can arbitrarily modify that string but I just have at least "-" and "number" because then I will need to do other things in the php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear whether you need to do a simple `preg_replace()` or `preg_replace_callback()` (because you "*need to do other things in the php code*").

The best solution that I can offer you now is to use this pattern that requires `[dr]`|`[/dr]` tagging and a `-` substring delimiter followed by one or more digits.

Pattern: ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fGTdiY/1))

```
#  ⬐⬐⬐------------⬐⬐⬐⬐--------------- match opening and closing tags
#  ￬￬￬￬￬           ￬￬￬￬￬￬￬ 
  ~\[dr](.+?)-(\d+)\[/dr]~
#        ￪￪￪   ⬑⬑⬑---------------------- capture one or more digits
#        ⬑⬑----------------------------- capture one or more of any character
```

With these two captured substrings, you can use `preg_replace()` to generate a new dynamic replacements string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/b2dY8))

```
$bbcode = '[dr]my name here-25[/dr]';
echo preg_replace('~\[dr](.+?)-(\d+)\[/dr]~', '<div>Reply to: <a href="user.php?id=$2">$1</a></div>', $bbcode);
```

Output:

```
<div>Reply to: <a href="user.php?id=25">my name here</a></div>
```

Comment: now your pattern works.
Only one thing: how can I get the "-number" part?
Example: [dr]my name here-25[/dr] I need of 25

Comment: Please better explain your process and include your coding attempt.  I can easily solve what you are doing if I can see your desired outcome.  I have a  feeling that you want `preg_replace_callback()` .

Comment: `$search = array(
'{\[dr](.+?)-(\d+)\[/dr]}siU'
);        

$replace = array(
'<div>Reply to: \\2 [here I need a link to -NUMBER]</div>'
);

$newvar = preg_replace($search, $replace, $newvar);  `

Comment: So what will your exact desired output be, given your sample input?  `<div>Reply to: <a href="user.php?id=[thenumber]">[thenumber]</a></div>`? or do you need to run a "lookup" and replace [thenumber] with some other value?

Comment: the href tag you indicated would be perfect for me

Comment: I've updated my answer with what I think you would like to see as a replacement. I used `my name here` as the hyperlink text and the the `[number]` in the link url.

Comment: thank you so much! it's right my goal: it works fine!